# Command line tools for copying parts of video

Tags: video, command-line, editing, encoding

I have a divx video of 10 mins. I want to copy two parts from it , minutes 2 to 6 and 8 to 10 and create another video by merging the two. how can I do it using lightweight command line tools. Either on Windows or Linux?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps ffmpeg/mencoder (available on either platform).

To split:

```
ffmpeg -ss [start_seconds] -i [input_file] -t [duration_seconds] [outputfile]
```

For example:

```
ffmpeg -ss 2 -i input.avi -c copy -t 4 video1.avi
ffmpeg -ss 8 -i input.avi -c copy -t 2 video2.avi
```

To merge:

```
mencoder -ovc copy -oac copy video1.avi video2.avi -o output.avi
```

If your video/audio is out of synchronization, you might need to re-encode them, e.g. with XviD for an AVI container, and MP3 audio:

```
ffmpeg -ss 2 -i input.avi -c:v libxvid -qscale:v 3 -c:a libmp3lame -q:a 3 -t 2 output.avi
```

Change the `qscale` parameter to a lower value for higher quality, and the same for `q:a` for the audio parts.

Comment: does it work on divx encoded videos? let me check..

Comment: small corrections ;  `-t duration'  :   Restrict the transcoded/captured video sequence to the duration specified in seconds. hh:mm:ss[.xxx] syntax is also supported. 
 
 `-ss position'  :   Seek to given time position in seconds. hh:mm:ss[.xxx] syntax is also supported. 

Itried this and it worked but the video and the audio are time shifted and also there's a big difference in the original and output quality.The output's very degraded. DivX is a variant of MPEG4 hence we can ffmpeg as it can produce MPEG4 on its own

Comment: I left out the hh:mm:ss given the context of your answer. 

I admit, I tried this in a ssh connection to home. Didn't verify the quality. 

Perhaps try doing it all w/ mencoder?

Comment: the video and the audio are time shifted

Answer (score 0):

To split the video there's a hand command line tool called [jumptheshark](http://luisbg.blogalia.com/historias/63307).